# Group MongoDB documents by field

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have a collection of say questions like below -

```
{
    question: "what's the question?",
    answer: "some answer",
    points: 10
},
{
    question: "what's the question again?",
    answer: "some answer again",
    points: 40
},
...
```

The questions which are answered will have an `answer` in it's document and vice-versa. I want to group all the answered and not-answered questions using `aggregate`, to get an output like -

```
{
  answered: [{...}, {...}],
  unanswered: [{...}, {...}]
}
```

How would the aggregate query for this look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple way to do this.

One is using `$facet` as follows :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "answered": [
        {
          $match: {
            answer: {
              $exists: true
            },
            
          },
          
        },
        
      ],
      "unanswered": [
        {
          $match: {
            answer: {
              $exists: false
            },
            
          },
          
        },
        
      ],
      
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: can I use a $match with $facet?

Comment: Yes for sure, here a mongoplayground link of my code  : https://mongoplayground.net/p/jwTjzGPhOk4

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `$group` instead of `$facet`, as `$facet` does not use indices:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$group: {
      _id: 0,
      answered: {$push: {$cond: [
            {$eq: [{$toBool: "$answer"}, true]},
            "$$ROOT",
            "$$REMOVE"
      ]}},
      unanswered: {$push: {$cond: [
            {$ne: [{$toBool: "$answer"}, true]},
            "$$ROOT",
            "$$REMOVE"
      ]}},
  }},
  {$unset: "_id"}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SUN1CoeMSMn)

Comment: You can replace  `{$eq: [{$toBool: "$answer"}, true]},` by `{$toBool: "$answer"}` and `{$ne: [{$toBool: "$answer"}, true]},` to `{$not:{ $toBool:"$answer"}, },` but nice answer, didn't know the `$toBool` operator.